# How to check if value is in dictionary?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON and I want to check if the response contains a value that I will type in a search bar.

I've just got the whole JSON file of 1666 objects and append it into my objects array and then I'm searching for value, but it takes too long.

```
func parseJSON(json: JSON, parse: ParseType) {
  var i = 0
  var j = 0
  switch parse {
    case .group:
      for elements in json["groups"] {
        if let groupId = json["groups"][i]["id"].int {
          let groupName = json["groups"][i]["name"].string
          // print(groupId)
          let group = Groups(id: groupId, name: groupName!)

          groupsArray.append(group)
          i += 1
        } else {
          print("Error can't parse JSON")
        }
      }

      func getGroupsData(url: String, groupName: String) {
      Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
          print("Is Success")
          let json = JSON(response.result.value)
          self.parseJSON(json: json, parse: .group)
          if let group = self.groupsArray.first(where: {$0.name == groupName}) {
            print("found \(group)")
            let searchScheduleUrl = url + "\(group.id)"
            self.getGroupSchedule(url: searchScheduleUrl)
          } else {
            print("Can't find group")
          }
        } else {
          print(response.result.error)
        }
      }
    }
```

And here is **JSON**:

```
{
 "groups" : [
   {
    "faculty" : {
    "id" : 101,
    "abbr" : "ИнГО",
    "name" : "Гуманитарный институт"
  },
  "id" : 26262,
  "spec" : "47.06.01 Философия, этика и религиоведение",
  "kind" : 3,
  "level" : 3,
  "name" : "33865\/4702",
  "type" : "common"
},
{
  "faculty" : {
    "id" : 95,
    "abbr" : "ИКНТ",
    "name" : "Институт компьютерных наук и технологий"
  },
  "id" : 27432,
  "spec" : "09.03.04 Программная инженерия",
  "kind" : 0,
  "level" : 1,
  "name" : "в13534\/22",
  "type" : "evening"
},
{
  "faculty" : {
    "id" : 92,
    "abbr" : "ИСИ",
    "name" : "Инженерно-строительный институт"
  },
  "id" : 26322,
  "spec" : "08.06.01 Техника и технологии строительства",
  "kind" : 3,
  "level" : 1,
  "name" : "13163\/0801",
  "type" : "common"
}, and so on...
```

I want to check for example:
 if name: "13541/1" is in dictionary and if it is i want to get it's id

Comment: If you are coding in Swift 4 or later you should drop swiftyJSON and use Swift Codable protocol to structure the data returned by the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let groups: [Group]
}

struct Group: Codable {
    let faculty: Faculty
    let id: Int
    let spec: String
    let kind, level: Int
    let name, type: String
}

struct Faculty: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let abbr, name: String
}
```

---

```
do {
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:data) 
    if let item = res.groups.first(where:{  $0.name == YourName }) {
      print(item.id)
    }
}
catch {
  print(error)
}
```